# b-form-input formatter not formatting number

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to have input numbers show with comma separation as users type. I am using bootstrap-vue's b-form-input. I believe the formatter is the correct option for this. When I use the formatter, I am not seeing the formatted results as I expected. Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/spike_wood/34wqme5n/9/

**As a point of clarification, the intent is keep the variable points as a Number, to perform math and so forth. The goal is to display the number in the input field in a readable way when it is very large.

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <b-form>
      <b-form-group
        label-for="totalPoints"
        description="Enter points."
      >
        <label for="totalPoints">Total Points</label>
        <b-input-group append="pts">
          <b-form-input
            style="width: 20%"
            id="totalPoints"
            v-model.number="points"
            placeholder="Enter your total points"
            :formatter="numberFormat"
          />
        </b-input-group>
      </b-form-group>
    </b-form>
    <h3>Unformatted Points: {{ points }}</h3>
    <h3>Formatted Points: {{ numberFormat(points) }}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my javascript:

```
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        name: 'BootstrapVue',
        points: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
        numberFormat(value) {
        return value === 0 ? '' : value.toLocaleString();
      }
    }
  })
```

Please let me know if I am approaching this incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking what I learned from Hiws answer, I have created a display string for the field, and a variable to capture the actual number. This allows me to perform math on the number while having the readable format.

My script now looks like the following. I also moved to a type coercion operator in my return statement, to remove 0 only strings from the input field

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        points: 0,
        displayPoints: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      numberFormat(value) {
        this.points = Number(value.replace(/\D/g, ''))
        return value == '0' ? '' : this.points.toLocaleString();
      }
    }
  })
```

And my html looks like the following. I removed all number casting from the input, as it does not play nice with the commas I was inserting.

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <b-form>
      <b-form-group
        label-for="totalPoints"
        description="Enter points."
      >
        <label for="totalPoints">Total Points</label>
        <b-input-group append="pts">
          <b-form-input
            style="width: 20%"
            id="totalPoints"
            v-model="displayPoints"
            placeholder="Enter your total points"
            :formatter="numberFormat"
          />
        </b-input-group>
      </b-form-group>
    </b-form>
    <h3>Unformatted Points: {{ points }}</h3>
    <h3>Formatted Points: {{ displayPoints }}</h3>
    <h3>Math on Points: {{ points + points }}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the string and join them with comma.

```
methods: {
    numberFormat(value) {
        return value.replace(/,/g, '').split('').join(',')
  }
}
```

But the above case will always add comma after every string and accept no comma in the string

Comment: It seems that using the number and toLocaleString() method do the same thing, though focused on a number and not a string. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the value sent to your formatter function will always be a string, but right now you're checking for a number.

So you need to do this instead to get your formatter working with your current code.

```js
numberFormat(value) {
  return value === '0' ? '' : value.toLocaleString();
}
```

---

You should also not use `v-model.number`, but the `number` prop if you want the v-model value to be output as a number. (formatter will still be a string)

> v-model modifiers .number and .trim can cause unexpected cursor jumps when the user is typing (this is a Vue issue with v-model on custom components). Avoid using these modifiers. Use the number or trim props instead.

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input#input-type (under ***Caveats with input types***)

Comment: This is a great point and helped me figure out the immediate issue. The .toLocaleString() only works on numbers, and the formatter passes in the value as a string. I am looking for the result from the field to be a Number (in the variable points), but the display to be the well formatted string.